# Where did "Show_Advanced_Permissions" gconf-editor setting go?

Tags: nautilus, permissions

I find the default display of "Permissions" in nautilus (when viewing properties of a folder/file) difficult to use.

To solve this, I always used gconf-editor in 10.04 to change to the following:

```
gconf-editor: apps > nautilus > preferences > show_advanced_permissions
```

[image]

How can I get permissions to look like above in 12.04? The gconf-editor setting is not listed under nautilus in 12.04. Has it been moved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run this command in a terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.extensions.preferences show-advanced-permissions true
```

Or use [dconf-editor [image: Install dconf-editor]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/dconf-editor):

```
org > gnome > nautilus > extensions > preferences > show-advanced-permissions
```

[image]

Comment: gsettings? is this something I need to install?

Comment: could you please say more about this? I can find no "org.gnome.nautilus.preferences" in dconf or gconf.

Comment: I've edited to fix the key name...this answer should work too now.